# FoxPro / Intellisense not working in the editor. How can I fix it?

Tags: intellisense, visual-foxpro

I am new at FoxPro.

In a program I use, I do not see any intellisense in the editor.

Searched for it in the internet and saw that there is intellisense manager.

In my program it seems that intellisense is enabled.

One interesting point is that intellisense is working as desired in the command window.

But it is not working in the editor.

I tried <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`J`</kbd> and `Edit/List Members`, still not working.

**Do I skip something?**

Comment: Did you look through all of the "Intellisense not working" questions listed in the "Related" list to the right? ======>>>>>>

Comment: @KenWhite unfortunately none of them is the same issue.

Comment: Are you using the native VFP code editor?

Comment: @TamarE.Granor yes, it is native VFP editor.

Comment: What kind of editing window? What items are you expecting IntelliSense for?

Comment: Is Syntax Coloring active in your editor window (Edit->Properties)? Menu items for Edit->List Members etc. do not get greyed out if syntax features are disabled. What's the content of _VFP.EditorOptions?

Comment: @DarthGizka yes, syntax coloring is active. But I am not sure if I understood correctly about what you mean by _VFP.EditorOptions. If it is tools/options/editor, there seems nothing interesting. Background compile option is `Underline`.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor I would like intellisense for functions and procedures of the classes.

Comment: EditorOptions is a property of the _VFP system variable, and it controls things like IntelliSense. "help _vfp s" should take you close. Do you have a debug output window open so that you can see when Fox complains about things? ("Foxcode table not found, ..." etc.) Starting VFP9.exe with parameter -A can exclude problems related to settings stored in the registry, ideally in an empty directory so that it doesn't pick up some config.fpw and foxuser.dbf that happen to be lying around. If one of those is in the directory with VFP9.exe, move them elsewhere temporarily.

Comment: "Tools->Intellisense Manager" is disabled if there is stuff missing in your setup (i.e. not found, not there, whatever).

Comment: @DarthGizka thank you for all your effort. `Trace`, `Watch`, `Call Stack`, `Debug Output`, `Locals` windows are all open when debugging, none of them complaining. I tried the other advises also, but didnt work for me unfotunately. (By the way tools/intellisense manager is not disabled. It is enabled and intellisense is working in command window)

Comment: @serdar, are you talking about VCX classes or PRG classes. If the latter, you have to do a little more work. In the IntelliSense Manager, click on the Types tab, then click Classes, change the "Files of type" dropdown to PRG, and point to your program. Then close the IntelliSense Manager.